# Where Cocos2d-x stores user data under Android?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

My project was saving user data using some internal cocos2d-x system and now I can't find my files manually. I moved my project to another C++ engine and I need to have an access to those files. Now I can't execute a code using cocos2d-x so I need to open those files but I don't know where I can't find it.

Could you please give me a few paths where cocos2d-x stores user data? I can try to took for my user option files. Where it can be stored on Android?

My cocos-project was compiled about 1 year ago if it has any sense :)

Comment: is it the same app with same identifier/bundle ID? Because apps are sandboxed, so if this is a new app it can't acces the data of the old app.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Yes it's an app with exactly the same identifier (signed with the same android-certificate and it has exactly the same package name). So I think it should be in the same sandbox but I don't know where I can try to find my files.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D How can I access the data if it's the old app? But now it's written with Marmalade C++ Engine.

Comment: open your old project and run it, set a breakpoint where you store some data, step into the method (cocos2d is open source after all) until you find where and how it creates the path to the file. Probably some documents or appdata folder, obtained through a framework method.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I know it but I haven't an access to my old sources. That's why I need to know all paths where cocos2d-x stores the data.

Comment: you have access to cocos2dx, do you remember what function you used to store data? If not, would you recognize it if you found it in the sources? If so, you should be able to find the code that generates the path to save data and if it's not clear what that location is, post that code here in a new question and someone should be able to answer that.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D No, I don't have the source code anymore that's why I need to check all pathes. What's the sandbox's path? Where it places in Android file system?

Comment: i mean just the cocos2d-x v2.x sources, they are available online

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Actually I don't remember which method I used to save the data :) Is there a way to get a name of the directory (and its path) where cocos2d-x saves the data? Maybe be you know the name of the path of a package?

Comment: no idea, and i've never really used cocos2dx nor android sdk